# Windows Cmd Loop name and create folders

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I'm trying to figure out how to create a certain number of folders in a Windows batch file. I want to ask the user how many folder they want, and then use that collected number to loop the asking for names of those folders and make them. Here is what I have so far:

```
pushd C:\Users\%username%\Desktop

set /p FolderLoop="How many folders?: " 

for /l %%x in (1, 1, %FolderLoop%) do (
    set /p folder="Folder: " %%x
    md %folder% %%x
)
```

The problem I keep having is that I can not make the folders with the proper collected names. The closest I have gotten so far is creating the right amount of folders, but with sequential numeric names (1,2,3, etc.) based om the FolderLoop variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
pushd C:\Users\%username%\Desktop
set /p FolderLoop="How many folders?: " 
for /l %%x in (1, 1, %FolderLoop%) do (
    set /p "folder=Folder: " 
    md "!folder!"
)
```

(the `%%x` after `set /p` does nothing. I removed it. I also removed it from `md`, you don't need it - except you want the counter be part of the foldername.)

Comment: This is it! Thank you! I could tell it was basically ignoring the variable I was trying to call for the folder names. This fixed it!
(One thing, just for other readers, delayed in enabledelayedexpansion is missing the e. :) )

Comment: `e` inserted...  btw, you can also use `%userprofile%\desktop`

Answer (score 2):

You need to read any of the hundreds of responses on SO with regard to `delayedexpansion`.

Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the **entire** block is parsed and **then** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **at the time the block is parsed** - before the block is executed - the same thing applies to a `FOR ... DO (block)`.

Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, `REM` statements rather than the broken-label remark form (`:: comment`) should be used because labels terminate blocks, confusing `cmd`.

Hence, `IF (something) else (somethingelse)` will be executed using the values of `%variables%` at the time the `IF` is encountered.

Two common ways to overcome this are 1) to use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and use `!var!` in place of `%var%` to access the changed value of `var` or 2) to call a subroutine to perform further processing using the changed values.

Note therefore the use of `CALL ECHO %%var%%` which displays the changed value of `var`. `CALL ECHO %%errorlevel%%` displays, but sadly then RESETS errorlevel.

Comment: This was extremely in depth and informative. Thank you so much!